# generate random number in omnet++ ini files without any distribution function

Tags: random, ini, omnet++, inet

how can i generate random number between 0 and 1 without using any distribution function in my ini file. in fact i want to "0.7s" in this code be random:

```
**.host1.mytest[*].sendInterval = 0.7s
```

send interval is also configured in the NED file as follow:

```
volatile double sendInterval @unit("s") = default(1s);
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign a random value from the range (0, 1) write in `omnetpp.ini`:

```
**.host1.mytest[*].sendInterval = uniform(0s, 1s)
```

Comment: this solution is uses distribution function, the problem is that the the result of my execution is will be close to each other, this is part of my result:
648594
645894
643572
647082
646866
650376
648756
645732
648918

i need high change and result be far from each other.

Comment: When do you read `sendInterval` parameter in your code? Could you present your code?